# UV image 'path not writable'

Tags: texturing, uv-image-editor

When I <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>S</kbd> on the *UV Image Editor* so that I want to save just the image of my UV laid image then Blender returns:

> path is not writable

What does this mean?

Comment: Is that the first time you save the image? If it is the first time then there is no path associated with the image. First use F3 button to save the file on your drive.

Comment: Also make sure that the file is not open in another program.

Comment: @Denis Should be an answer.

Comment: @Denis Can you write up a small answer, thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One of the reasons that you can not use <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>S</kbd> is that the generated image does not have a link to a file on the hard drive. Instead use <kbd>F3</kbd> in the UV/Image Editor window to save as a new file. When the image is linked to a file on the hard drive you can use <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>S</kbd> shortcut to override the existing file.

Another reason can be, that the image file is open in another program, that is preventing from the file to be overwritten.